# Arduino Uno and Arduino Yun software. Which version of the IDE works with both best?

Tags: arduino-yun, software

I have been working with Unos and just started working with Yun. I have 1.86 currently installed but the Yun starts up saying to use 1.5.6-r2 Beta IDE. Should I uninstall 1.8.6 and install 1.5.6-r2?

Thanks for your help.

Lisa

Comment: Get rid of the Yún. Buy a WeMos or NodeMcu or a Raspberry Pi. Every minute you put into the Yún will turn out to be wasted time.

Comment: I'm also learning RaspberryPi and Galileo, along with some tiny ones.

Comment: The Galileo had a lot of problems and has been "retired". The Arduino boards with ethernet or wifi chips are okay. Stay away from the boards that have a simple microcontroller and a advanced wifi module. The WeMos can do everything those can do and more. The Raspberry Pi is reliable and fun, it will never disappoint you.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  What do you think of WickedNode kits?  and 8266?  useful?  I'm mostly wanting to "SMART"-up my home and security.  I have a ton of sensors.  Today I'm playing with an RF send/receive modules.  This probably isn't good conversation on this thread.  Do you mind if I occasionally ask advice through PM?

Comment: StackExchange has no PM. The WeMos is EPS8266. The WickedNode seems too specific, I like more freedom. The RFM96 is a good transceiver, it is used by Adafruit. The RadioHead is a good library, but uses a lot of memory. RadioHead is fine for ARM processors (Arduino Zero, Arduino M0, Arduino Due). If you make something that should last at least 10 years, buy from good companies (they use higher quality components) and try to use the most common and most often used standard modules/boards. Wifi at 2.4GHz is common, therefor the WeMos or NodeMcu is a good choice. The Raspberry Pi is always good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yun startup was written when the normal IDE didn't support the yun, so you had to use a release candidate of a future version.

Those days are long gone.

Always use the latest version of the IDE.